# extjs ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, extjs

everyone!
i'm trying to create ExtJs form and post some data to my php script. heres the code of the button:

```
    var btnChk = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Check',
    handler: function(){
    var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
    conn.request({
           method:'POST',
           url: 'tmp.php',
           success: function(){alert('ok')},
           failure: function(){alert('not ok')},
           params: { foo: 'bar' }
    });
```

when i hit this button the message is **'ok'**, so i guess it's a success.
but i can't see any `$_POST` in my php - it's just an empty array.
what i'm doing wrong? (i'm realy new to ext and ajax)

Comment: try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `success` return doesn't just mean that the data was sent, but that the file was located and successfully sent data.

What PHP code are you using?

Be sure to use the `$_POST` variable array and not `$_GET`

Try the following conn.request code

```
var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
conn.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'tmp.php',
    params: {
        foo: "bar"
    },
    success: function(responseObject) { alert(responseObject.responseText); },
    failure: function() { alert("Failed!"); }
});
```

What does the `responseText` say?

Comment: php is as simple as `print_r($_POST);` so the porblem is on server side?

Comment: I've added a test for you to add.

Comment: it prints `Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)` but when i'm trying to request tmp.php from my browser i see that `$_POST` is empty.

Comment: Because if you're going directly to tmp.php?foo=bar then your `$_POST` will always be empty, because in fact, you're requesting via a `$_GET`

Comment: i know the difference between post and get =) i just can't realize how can i use POST in my php script

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want. If you want it to work for both you could use `$_REQUEST` which is a combination of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`

Comment: i'm really sorry for wasting your time. i had a silly mistaje in my code=) and great thanks for your test, it helped me much.